# Google Analytics 4 Custom Event Report

Tags: google-analytics-4

I'm sending custom events to Google Analytics with JavaScript (from within my SPA).

```js
public logMealEvent(selected_meal, selected_food): void {
  gtag('event', 'my-custom-event', {
      meal: selected_meal,
      food: selected_food
  });
}

this.logMealEvent('breakfast', 'Toast');
this.logMealEvent('breakfast', 'Eggs');
this.logMealEvent('breakfast', 'Eggs');
this.logMealEvent('lunch', 'Sandwich');
this.logMealEvent('lunch', 'Soup');
this.logMealEvent('dinner', 'Chicken Tikka Masala');
```

"meal" and "food" have both been registered as custom dimensions in the Custom Definitions section of the Configure menu.

Now I'm trying to create a Report too see the data using Explore -> FreeForm.

What I'd really like to see is all the data, so something like:

```js
Meal          Food
breakfast     Toast
breakfast     Eggs
breakfast     Eggs
lunch         Sandwhich
lunch         Soup
dinner        Chicken Tikka Masala
```

But this doesn't seem to be possible.

I'd settle for:

```js
breakfast     3
lunch         2
dinner        1
```

But that isn't working.  I get this:

[image]

Obviously I'm doing something wrong.  This is the guide I'm using:
https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/how-to-track-custom-events-with-google-analytics-4/

As well as this:
https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/exploration-reports-in-google-analytics-4/

Thanks.